How to compare files from .war file with a branch
I need to compare a .war file (it's like a compressed file with all file project on it) with a master branch.
I have a script to compare 2 branches, I need to compare a file (or folders btw) with my master branch.
I tried this, but is not what I want
    @echo off
color 60
echo == PolicyCenter1020 ==
echo.
echo == VERSUS ==
echo.

set module="PC1020"

set branch1="maintenance-pre"

set branch2="master"

cd C:\GW1020\%module%\modules\configuration
git difftool --dir-diff --tool=winmerge %branch1%..%branch2%
echo.
echo == END ==
echo.
pause


Have you tried using Beyond Compare's (free version) folder compare? For scripting purposes, git diftool might work if you use it like
git difftool --dir-diff --tool=winmerge %branch1% %branch2% -- %targetPath%
